# Getting information about a suggestion from a suggestion ID in Google Docs API

Tags: get, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm currently using the documents.get API method to retrieve documents with suggestions inline, returned as so:

```
{
   "startIndex": 108,
   "endIndex": 159,
   "textRun": {
     "content": "This is some content that I have suggested to insert",
     "suggestedInsertionIds": [
        "suggest.fakesuggestionId123"
     ],
     "textStyle": {}
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve information about this suggestion (i.e. who wrote it and when), but I can't see any endpoints in which the suggestedInsertionId values can be queried. Is there a way to retrieve this information in either the Drive or Docs APIs (outside of exporting to docx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Currently this information is not available via API

It is available for comments via [Comments:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/get), but not for suggestions.
There is a related [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/138526209) for it on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

You can "star" it or comment on it to increase visibility.